# How to return local variable value from a function written in R using spark.lapply()

Tags: r, apache-spark, lapply, databricks, sparkr

I have defined some functions written in the R Language... Now I am trying to use "**spark.lapply**" to parallelize the function.
So exactly what happening is I am defining one empty vector inside the function and values are getting populated inside the function.

**input_1** : R dataframe (iris data)

**Function Defination:**

```
agg_sum <- function(RowNum){
 test <- "Hello"
  input_1$sum <- input_1$Sepal.Length + RowNum
}
```

**Function calling** :

```
output_1 <- spark.lapply(1:5,function(RowNum) agg_sum(RowNum))
```

So, if I am calling the vector later in code after calling the function using spark.lapply(), I am getting the error: `Error:object 'test' not found`

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code so that others better understand the problem in order to help you?

Comment: @Waldi i have added my function sample, what i am trying to acheive

Comment: As far as I can remember, global variables like `input_1` have to be declared in `Spark` before you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Just return a list with all the values you want to export from each function execution. It is best to avoid thinking in terms of global or mutable variables and picture the computation as applying a map function.

Following your sample code:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

sparkR.session(master = "local[4]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))

agg_fun <- function(row_num){
  internal_var <- paste(c("Hello", row_num), collapse = "")
  main_result <- row_num + 1000
  
  list(internal_var = internal_var, main_result = main_result)
}

output_1 <- spark.lapply(1:3, function(RowNum) agg_fun(RowNum))
```

The `agg_fun` computes a `main_result` together with an `internal_var`. The function returns the list with both values. `spark.lapply` will combine the results together as a list of lists:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$internal_var
[1] "Hello1"

[[1]]$main_result
[1] 1001


[[2]]
[[2]]$internal_var
[1] "Hello2"

[[2]]$main_result
[1] 1002


[[3]]
[[3]]$internal_var
[1] "Hello3"

[[3]]$main_result
[1] 1003
```

Then, if you want to select only the `internal_var` values, iterate over them:

```
> sapply(output_1, FUN = function(x) x$internal_var)
[1] "Hello1" "Hello2" "Hello3"
```